# Huge time difference between Python 2 and Python 3 to load and image using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, python-3.5

I am a beginner in OpenCV. I built OpenCV on Windows using CMake with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 compiler and Shared DLL option. Here is a small example code from the tutorial

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

img = cv2.imread('images.jpg',0)
f = time.clock()
cv2.imshow('image',img)
f = time.clock() - f
print(f)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What I found surprising was the image took a long time to load. (2 seconds according to the time module, but the long delay was apparent). I then installed Python 2, copied the prebuilt 'cv2.pyd' into site package of Python 2 and tried running the same program. This time, the image loaded much quicker compared to previous run with python 3.

I guessed it could be a reason with dynamic library rather than static library. So this time, I build OpenCV with SHARED_LIBRARY option set to 'off'. I then copied the cv2.cp35-amd64.pyd to the site package of Python 3 installation. To my surprise, that didn't make a difference. The loading of image still took a significant time.

What could be the reason?